# Spring roo security setup with CUD but not R?

Tags: spring-security, spring-roo

I am trying to to setup a security policy in Spring such that anyone can read any entities created in roo but only the admin user (specified in the `applicationContext-security.xml`) can create/update/delete.   It seems to me I should be able to achieve my goal by customizing `applicationContext-security.xml` but I can't figure out a way.  I thought of using intercept-url like:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/anyEntity/*?form" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

but this config does not cover DELETE because it is a hidden field in POST (according to the  doc, post method is supported but there is no doc on how to specify a hidden field value in the intercept-url tag)

Another way would be to use @secured on entity setter methods. I currently rely on roo to generate the getters/setters so I would like to avoid using it if possible

I can also write a custom controller to do the filtering I suppose.  But seems to me I should be able to just customize the configuration.  I must be missing something obvious because a public read-only policy should be a very common strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the method="DELETE" attribute to intercept-url because roo converts the hidden method field to the http method.

There is also some more information [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?104113-How-to-secure-just-some-of-the-scaffolded-controller-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
    <!-- only user role can use modify methods -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="DELETE" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="PUT" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <!-- any role can use GET methods -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="HEAD" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="OPTIONS" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="TRACE" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```